# OAuth2 not working in meteor mobile app

Tags: javascript, meteor, linkedin-api, meteor-accounts

I am doing a simple linkedin oauth using the package yefim:accounts-linkedin. The code is as simple as possible:

```
<template name="createAccount">
    <div class="container">
        <h2 align="center">Create Account</h2>
        <div class="">
            <button class="connectWithLinkedin">Connect with LinkedIn</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template> 


Template.createAccount.events({
    'click .connectWithLinkedin':function(event,template){
            Meteor.loginWithLinkedin({
                loginStyle:'popup'
            }, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("error encountered "+err);
                }
                else{
                    Router.go('linkedinForm');
                }
            });
        }
})
```

The app works as expected in browser. The click of the button as the user his username and password, and when the user click 'allow access' button, he is redirected to the respective page and in the backend a document is created in the 'user' collection.

But the problem arises, when I start using this app in mobile. Some doc says that oauth2 does not work in local. So i even push my code into production as ******.meteor.com, but still oauth2 does not work in mobile device nor in simulator.

I get the following errors,

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mouse' of undefined
This error is for dsyko_jquery-ui-touch-punch package that I am using.

Uncaught ReferenceError: Tracker is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: Spacebars is not defined
Exception from Tracker recompute function:
Error: no domrange

Can anyone guide, what is the problem and how can I solve them.

Comment: I am running my app as follows: meteor run android-device --mobile-server https://XXXX.meteor.com